# Windows 7 License deactivation

Tags: windows-7, windows, license

Until unless the machine is not formatted till time the license is activated on particular machine. But however I want to deactivate the license from my side? is it possible or is their any way to deactivate the license without informing the user?
How to escalate the license to my Microsoft account?

Comment: I think I speak for everyone when I say: umm, what?

Answer (score 2):

You do not have to deactivate a computer if you are moving your license from one computer to another.  Whether a copy of Windows is licensed is a legal concept; it is separate from "activation" which is a technical matter.

If you have a retail copy of the OS which allows moving licenses between computers, you can simply install Windows on the new computer. As long as you no longer use the previous installation, you're not violating the license agreement. If the new copy of Windows will not activate (claiming that your license has already been used on another machine), you can contact Microsoft and they will allow the activation.

If you have an OEM copy of Windows, then odds are good that the license is tied to that particular machine; the license cannot be transferred between computers. You can reinstall Windows on the same machine but you cannot use a different set of hardware instead.

Comment: You just have to use the same Motherborad MS told me.